# How to set outputContext from inline editor in dialogflow v2 api

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm setting the responses via the inline editor eg:

```
function send_response(agent)
{

    agent.add("This is a response");

}
```

I would also like to set the outputContext via the inline editor as per the V2 api https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment

```
"outputContexts": [
    {
      "name": "projects/${PROJECT_ID}/agent/sessions/${SESSION_ID}/contexts/context name",
      "lifespanCount": 5,
      "parameters": {
        "param": "param value"
      }
    }
  ]
```

Wouldn't mind some advice on how to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can use `agent.setContext()` for this, see [this](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/blob/master/samples/parameters-contexts-and-rich-responses/functions/index.js) dialogflow sample for reference,

```
agent.setContext({
  "name": 'context-name',
  "lifespan": 1,
  "parameters":{"param": "param value"}
});
```

Comment: thanks. so i'm just a tiny bit confused. lets say I have two intents "Intent1" and "Intent2" and both intents are triggered by the word/training phrase "yes". If I go into the dialogflow intents tab and from there enter intent1-context and intent2-context into the respective contexts...when I send a response back from the inline editor/fulfilment with agent.add("obtain input from intent2"); how can I tell dialogflow to only accept user input for Intent2...is that what agent.setContext is for?

Comment: That is a slightly different question, tho one I think we can easily help you with, but best asked as a new StackOverflow question.

Comment: @Mike though context can be used for different tasks like remembering old data, you can also accomplish your task using context, you just have to set output context as "intent2-context" & lifespan `1` (may be more) and set "intent1-context" with lifespan `0`

Comment: FYI your Dialogflow sample link doesn't work anymore